# C# : why can I not use dynamic param in an extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Why can I not use dynamic param in an extension method, as in the following code:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void ExtMethod(this Program pg, object asdf) {
        new Program();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
        d.test = "test";
        new Program().ExtMethod(d.test);
        Extension.ExtMethod(new Program(), d.test);
    }
}
```

`new Program().ExtMethod(d.test);` is throwing a compile time error.

But `Extension.ExtMethod(new Program(), d.test);` is not causing any error.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Please be more specific with your question.

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##bZDBDoIwDIbve4rGEyTICxBvciSaeDQe5jZhRjayVsUYnx3HQIXEXpp0//f/7QQuBYqua67HixaAxMk3ceGIkLekDGpr2JMx8DUX3ayWvaZQVFkZUaURts6WjtfQlIk9npUg4ChPMTwD35dR948qirMwfrEXG62H4PGdDdQ0ruDaREhOm3J/AO5KjIPm5y8fhtdeLmEVsnYPJFWn62Gc5m3DjbSbsNxngcClpJA8tOj7Ivu/cPq7dwAmDt/vmohmcAIzxp/dt657Aw): _Program.cs(14,9): error CS1973: 'Program' has no applicable method named 'ExtMethod' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax._

Comment: As far as I know C# does not allow dynamic parameter in extension methods.

Answer (score 6):

This is by design, and part of the specification. From the ECMA C# 5 standard, section 12.7.6.3:

> In a method invocation (§12.6.6.2) of one of the forms [...] if the normal processing of the invocation finds no applicable methods, an attempt is made to process the construct as an extension method invocation. **If `expr` or any of the args has compile-time type dynamic, extension methods will not apply.**

The underlying reason for this is that dynamic binding is intended to give the same result as binding at compile-time would... but for extension methods, that would mean retaining all the `using` directives at execution time. That would be *possible*, but I suspect it would be very expensive in terms of invocation performance, and the C# design team decided not to go that way.

Comment: I do not understand what "retaining using directives" hast to do with dynamic arguments. Can you please explain this? I would be very grateful!

Comment: @JosefBiehler: Extension methods are resolved based on the `using` directives you have - for example, you wouldn't be able to use LINQ methods without `using System.Linq;` (unless you called them as `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(...)` etc). So in order to behave the same way at execution time with dynamic binding, the code would need to "remember" all the `using` directives applicable at the point of binding.

Comment: i see. It is all about finding the correct method, which is aplicable for the given set of parameters, within all available namespaces. Well, this would indeed kill performance

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `d.test` to an object, in other words write;

`new Program().ExtMethod((object)d.test);`

Comment: this is my question why I can not directly(without typecasting) pass dynamic param in extension method but I can pass directly(without typecasting) using extension method as a static method.